# undefined value working in jquery 1.8.3 but not in 1.9.1

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-1.9, jquery-1.8

in 1.8.3 my flow goes in to this if condition but not in 1.9.1

```
    var order_node = $('div.oe_website_sale_tx_status');  
    if (! order_node || order_node.data('orderId') === undefined) {
        return;
    }
```

if `.data()` is changed in new version.

**HTML**

```
<div class="oe_website_sale_tx_status" data-order-id="order.id">
 .....
 .....
</div>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `order_node` will **never** be falsey (in either version of jQuery). It'll be a jQuery object, possibly an empty one, and objects are not falsey.

Comment: That code behaves the same way in both versions: [1.8.3 example](http://jsbin.com/sahaco/2), [1.9.1 example](http://jsbin.com/sahaco/2). And just for completeness, testing the case where it's not found: [1.8.3 example](http://jsbin.com/sahaco/3), [1.9.1 example](http://jsbin.com/sahaco/4). Side note: The current version of jQuery 1.x is 1.11.1, not 1.9.1.

Comment: Please either delete or correct the question.

Comment: this is correct question.

Comment: in 1.8.3 condition is True but in 1.9.1 every time condition false. why  ?

Comment: See the links above: That's simply not true.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

change orderID to "order-id" in data(). "order_node.data('order-id') "

check undefined using typeof. "typeof order_node.data('order-id') === 'undefined'"

```
var order_node = $('div.oe_website_sale_tx_status');  
if (! order_node || typeof order_node.data('order-id') === 'undefined') {
    return;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="oe_website_sale_tx_status" data-order-id="order.id">

</div>
```

Comment: jQuery makes the data available camelCased, so there's no point to the change you've suggested. Separately, "try this" answers are not useful, you must always say *what* you changed, and *why*. The question currently can't be answered, as it asserts something which isn't true.

Comment: @Nishitmaheta thnaks and u r right.but my problem is in If condition .